# If $a+b=c$, then find the max value of $d$ when $\frac1a+\frac1b=d$, where $a$, $b$, $c$ are positive integers.

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

If $a+b=c$, then find the maximum value of $d$ when $\frac1a+\frac1b=d$, where $a$, $b$, $c$ are positive integers.

---

I've tried using basic calculus to find the maximum value of $d$ expressed as a function of $a$.
That is, after some rearrangement, I get $$d=\frac{c}{ab}$$
which can be expressed as the following function (unless, I'm mistaken) $$d(a)=\frac{c}{a(c-a)}$$
where a, b, c $\in \mathbb{R}^+$.

Now, differentiating this function, then solving $d'(a)=0$ should give the value of $a$ at which $d(a)$ takes its maximum value (assuming the maximum and minimum values of $a$ can be ignored in this calculation).

The problem is I get the answer $d=4/c$ which is wrong, since for example, $1/1+1/2\neq4/3$.

Comment: Hint: in positive integers $\,c \ge a+1\,$, so $\,a \cdot (c-a) \ge 1 \cdot (c-1)\,$.

Comment: There are two things wrong with your solution $d=4/c$: (i) you are finding a stationary point in the real numbers $\mathbb R$, whereas the question stipulates that $a$ must be a positive integer; (ii) in fact $d=4/c$ is a _minimum_ over $\mathbb R$, not a maximum.

Comment: @TonyK I see.  Any ideas how to tackle it properly?

Comment: All terms are positive, so $c/(a(c-a))$ is maximum when $a(c-a)$ is minimum. Try a few integers and see what happens when $c=7$, say $-$ the result is very simple. Don't use calculus.

Comment: I forgot to add that $d$ should be expressed in terms of $c$, as this question is really a generalisation of cases where $c$ is known, and $a$ and $b$ are unknown.  

$ $ So for example, a single case of the problem could be $a + b = 147$ , find $d_{max}$ when $1/a + 1/b=d$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our claim is $1+\frac{1}{c-1}$ is the maximum possible attainable value
which attains at $a=1$ and $b=c-1$ or vice versa.

Say  $1+\frac{1}{c-1}$ is not the maximum and say the maximum is attained at $(a,b)$ such that $a$,$b$ is greater than $1$ as if one of them equals $1$ then we will get the same maximum. So $\frac{1}{a}\leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{b}\leq \frac{1}{2}$.

(As $a,b>1$ and they are positive integers).

Hence $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\leq 1$

Hence  $1+\frac{1}{c-1}$ is the maximum possible attainable value as it's greater than $1$!

Comment: What if $a$ and $b$ are not 1?  The question is asking for a general answer for *any* integer value of $a$ and $b$.
 $ $ Also, I forgot to add that $d$ should be expressed in terms of $c$, as this question is really a generalisation of cases where $c$ is known, and $a$ and $b$ are unknown.  

$ $ So for example, a single case of the problem could be $a + b = 147$ , find $d_{max}$ when $1/a + 1/b=d$.  Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: If $a,b$ are not then the maximum won't be attained at those points as $1/a+1/b$ would be less that $1$ and we can clearly see that a maximum of value greater than $1$ is attainable!

Comment: Yes, of course, I see it now! I was getting confused for no reason. This is brilliant.

Comment: In proving this, did you first start by trying out some values for $a$ and $b$, until you saw a plausible pattern, and went on to prove it?  (I'm now starting to wonder if this was even possible with calculus)

Comment: Yes, the fact that they were integers gave us valuable information